# How to load java.util.logging.config.file?

Tags: 16.04, java

I have a custom `log.properties` file which i am trying to load. When i run the command
`java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/orientdb/config/log.properties`, it doesn't do anything rather it spits this on the command line:-

```
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

Any idea on what i am doing wrong or how i can load that file? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
```

if `.level` is not set or is set to `INFO`, then `-Djava.util.logging.config.file` will not work

Comment: `handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = FINEST
com.orientechnologies.level = INFO
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=../log/orient-server.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=100
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1`

Comment: This is what my log.properties file look like. I did set it to the way you mentioned but i get the same result.